# monospace font in SVG has variable width glyphs

Tags: html, fonts, svg

I am trying to render an inline SVG that is base64 encoded that is using a monospace font and TEXT elements to display a simple dungeon.  But even though I am specifying a monospace font, the characters do not line up when the line includes glyphs.

This is on Chrome or Safari on Mac, so I assume the Courier font.

Example code:

```html
    <style>
        .base {
            fill: green;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
```

[image: Example image rendered using this]